# Windows Update: We can't finish the update. Try restarting your device and we'll try again. Error code: (0x8007000e)

Tags: windows, windows-update, wsus

I'm trying to use [Upsync](https://github.com/microsoft/update-server-server-sync/wiki/UpSync-V3-examples) to download and provide updates to Windows Update Agent. To see if it works, I looked up in `Settings > View update history > Uninstall updates` and uninstalled [this update](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=kb5013942), which is from `Security Updates` classification and `Windows 10, version 1903 and later` products:

```
2022-05 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21H1 for x64-based Systems (KB5013942)
```

I did this so I can download it with `Upsync` and do a test install.

1. First I ran this command to *fetch categories*:

   ```perl
   upsync pre-fetch --store-path .\store
   ```
2. Then I queried *the store* to obtain classification and product IDs of the mentioned update:

   ```perl
   PS C:\toupdate> upsync query --store-path .\store --package-type microsoft-classification --title-filter "security"
   Opening package source [.\store] Done!

   Query results:
   -----------------------------
   ID      : MicrosoftUpdate:0fa1201d-4330-4fa8-8ae9-b877473b6441:100
   Open ID : CF6F1A1466944A2341D4C6117C623184DF1B3380640DE73EB9964E027AF8D750C0EB7B3793E47C4838A67ACF44754DFF7F037845EE4B8FB51A2758DC86753BB8
    Title          : Security Updates
    Description    : A broadly released fix for a product-specific security-related vulnerability. Security vulnerabilities are rated based on their severity which is indicated in the Microsoftr security bulletin as critical, important, moderate, or low.
    Handler :
        CategoryType         : UpdateClassification
        ProhibitsSubcategories : True
        ProhibitsUpdates     : False
        DisplayOrder         :
        ExcludedByDefault    :
        HandlerType          : Category
   -----------------------------
   Returned 1 entries
   ```

   and then:

   ```perl
   PS C:\toupdate> upsync query --store-path .\store --package-type microsoft-product --title-filter "windows 10, version 1903 and later"
   Opening package source [.\store] Done!

   Query results:
   -----------------------------
   ID      : MicrosoftUpdate:b3c75dc1-155f-4be4-b015-3f1a91758e52:209
   Open ID : 61E944EC7CAED74461450FD2798932A6E71C1A52979D468CEFBB5C215F0DE44B58921750A28A898A8A06876A6A5BF58EFCBFEC396834FA5F3F8C52D44732B785
    Title          : Windows 10, version 1903 and later
    Description    : Windows 10, version 1903 and later (19H1+)
    Categories:
        Product                 : MicrosoftUpdate:6964aab4-c5b5-43bd-a17d-ffb4346a8e1d:100
                                  Windows
    Handler :
        CategoryType         : Product
        ProhibitsSubcategories : True
        ExcludedByDefault    : False
        ProhibitsUpdates     :
        DisplayOrder         :
        HandlerType          : Category
    Prerequisites:
        At least one of:
            ******************************
            *ID          : 6964aab4-c5b5-43bd-a17d-ffb4346a8e1d (is category)
            *              Windows
            ******************************
   [truncated]
   -----------------------------
   Returned 4 entries
   ```
3. Now I have the IDs and I can *fetch* the metadata for this product.

   ```perl
   PS C:\toupdate> upsync fetch --classification-filter 0fa1201d-4330-4fa8-8ae9-b877473b6441 --product-filter b3c75dc1-155f-4be4-b015-3f1a91758e52 --store-path .\store
   Creating package source [.\store] Done!
   Getting list of categories. This might take up to 1 minute ...
   Copying 0 package(s)
   Creating the query ...
   Filter:
       Classifications:
           0fa1201d-4330-4fa8-8ae9-b877473b6441
               Security Updates
       Products:
           b3c75dc1-155f-4be4-b015-3f1a91758e52
               Windows 10, version 1903 and later
   Getting list of updates. This might take up to 1 minute ...

   Done!
   ```
4. Finally, I *fetch the content*:

   ```perl
   PS C:\toupdate> upsync fetch-content --metadata-store-path .\store --content-store-path .\content --kbarticle-filter 5013942
   Opening package source [.\store] Done!
   Sync 3 files, 1718708760 bytes. Continue? (y/n)
   y
   ```

Since I had already downloaded the content, it doesn't redo the download. Now I can serve these updates to Windows Update Agent with this command:

```perl
upsync run-update-server --metadata-store-path .\store --content-source .\content --endpoint 127.0.0.1 --port 8530
```

I've changed the registry keys, so that it points to my server:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate]
"ElevateNonAdmins"=dword:00000001
"WUServer"="http://127.0.0.1:8530"
"WUStatusServer"="http://127.0.0.1:8530"
"DisableDualScan"=dword:00000001
"DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations"=dword:00000001

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU]
"AutoInstallMinorUpdates"=dword:00000001
"UseWUServer"=dword:00000001
"NoAutoUpdate"=dword:00000000
"AUOptions"=dword:00000002
"ScheduledInstallDay"=dword:00000000
"ScheduledInstallTime"=dword:00000003
"ScheduledInstallEveryWeek"=dword:00000001
```

I've uninstalled the update, and can confirm that it's no longer installed:

```perl
PS C:\toupdate> get-hotfix KB5013942
get-hotfix : Cannot find the requested hotfix on the 'localhost' computer. Verify the input and run the command again.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-hotfix KB5013942
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-HotFix], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetHotFixNoEntriesFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHotFixCommand
```

I also have this script that clears the cache, which I execute before each try:

```perl
if (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))  
{  
  $arguments = "& '" +$myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
  Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
  Break
}


write-host "stopping WSUS..." -foregroundcolor yellow
net stop wuauserv

write-host "stopping cryptSvc..." -foregroundcolor yellow
net stop cryptSvc

write-host "stopping BITS..." -foregroundcolor yellow
net stop bits

write-host "stopping msiserver..." -foregroundcolor yellow
net stop msiserver
 

write-host "deleting unnecessary registry keys..." -foregroundcolor yellow
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v AccountDomainSid /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v PingID /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v SusClientId /f
reg delete "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate" /v SusClientIDValidation /f

write-host "clearning cache" -foregroundcolor yellow
$files = "C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore", "C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsUpdate", "C:\Windows\System32\catroot2"

foreach($file in $files) {
    if(test-path $file) {
        remove-item $file -Force -Recurse
        write-host "deleted $file" -foregroundcolor green
    } else {
        write-host "$file not found" -foregroundcolor red
    }
}


net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver

wuauclt /resetauthorization /detectnow

write-host "done" -foregroundcolor green
pause
```

Then I run the `run-update-server` command:

```perl
PS C:\toupdate> upsync run-update-server --metadata-store-path .\store --content-source .\content --endpoint 127.0.0.1 --port 8530
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[63]
      User profile is available. Using 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys' as key repository and Windows DPAPI to encrypt keys at rest.
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\WSUS\upsync3\
Now listening on: http://127.0.0.1:8530
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

I then let the Windows Update Agent check for updates, and after a couple of minutes, it says:

```perl
We can't finish the update. Try restarting your device and we'll try again. Error code: (0x8007000e)
```

Here's the log:

```perl
2022/05/23 13:32:57.4371588 8984  9000  Shared          InitializeSus
2022/05/23 13:32:57.4384561 8984  9000  IdleTimer       Non-AoAc machine.  Aoac operations will be ignored.
2022/05/23 13:32:57.4387164 8984  9000  Agent           WU client version 10.0.19041.1288
2022/05/23 13:32:57.4395021 8984  9000  Agent           SleepStudyTracker: Machine is non-AOAC. Sleep study tracker disabled.
2022/05/23 13:32:57.4397685 8984  9000  Agent           Base directory: C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution
2022/05/23 13:32:57.4435698 8984  9000  Agent           Datastore directory: C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore\DataStore.edb
2022/05/23 13:32:57.4461507 8984  9000  DataStore       JetEnableMultiInstance succeeded - applicable param count: 5, applied param count: 5
2022/05/23 13:32:57.8087785 8984  9000  DataStore       Service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 added
2022/05/23 13:32:57.8282646 8984  9000  DataStore       Service 9482F4B4-E343-43B6-B170-9A65BC822C77 added
2022/05/23 13:32:57.8290945 8984  9000  DataStore       Data store successfully created
2022/05/23 13:32:57.8349788 8984  9000  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2022/05/23 13:32:57.8354202 8984  9000  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2022/05/23 13:32:57.8386062 8984  9000  Shared          Network state: Connected
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9643634 8984  9000  Agent           Created new random SusClientId 0985ee38-292f-4ee2-b190-1846121174fa. Old Id: none.
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9807711 8984  9000  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv6, cNetworkInterfaces = 0.
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9807917 8984  9000  Shared          UpdateNetworkState Ipv4, cNetworkInterfaces = 1.
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9808338 8984  9000  Shared          Power status changed
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884059 8984  9000  Agent           Initializing global settings cache
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884098 8984  9000  Agent           WSUS server: http://127.0.0.1:8530
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884120 8984  9000  Agent           WSUS status server: http://127.0.0.1:8530
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884143 8984  9000  Agent           Alternate Download Server: (null)
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884166 8984  9000  Agent           Fill Empty Content Urls: No
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884189 8984  9000  Agent           Target group: (Unassigned Computers)
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884210 8984  9000  Agent           Windows Update access disabled: No
2022/05/23 13:32:57.9884369 8984  9000  Agent           Do not connect to Windows Update Internet locations: Yes
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0079838 8984  9000  Agent           Initializing Windows Update Agent
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0082710 8984  9000  DownloadManager Download manager restoring 0 downloads
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0086757 8984  9000  Agent           CPersistentTimeoutScheduler | GetTimer, returned hr = 0x80248007
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0086963 8984  9000  Agent           CPersistentTimeoutEvent | Resubscribe, no existing/cached timer for Id=29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB.
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0087046 8984  9000  Agent           Adding timer: 
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0087191 8984  9000  Agent               Timer: 29A863E7-8609-4D1E-B7CD-5668F857F1DB, Expires 2022-05-24 09:02:57, not idle-only, not network-only
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0114841 8984  9000  IdleTimer       IdleTimer::NetworkStateChanged. Network connected? Yes
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0136814 8984  9056  DownloadManager Received power state change notification: Old: <unknown>; New: AC.
2022/05/23 13:32:58.0136972 8984  9056  DownloadManager Power state changed from <unknown> to AC.
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1404777 3044  4380  ComApi          * START *   SLS Discovery
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1487226 8984  9032  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 1) started; operation # 4; does use network; is not at background priority
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1530161 3044  4380  ComApi          *QUEUED* SLS Discovery
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1777353 8984  3020  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 1, operation # 4) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1874117 3044  3016  ComApi          *RESUMED* Discovery
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1874318 3044  3016  ComApi          Exit code = 0x00000000, Result code = 0x8024500C
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1874333 3044  3016  Api             * END *   Discovery ClientId
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1901311 3044  4380  ComApi          *FAILED* [8024500C] Method failed [CSLSClientProxy::GetSLSDataChunk:256]
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1920357 3044  4380  ComApi          * START *   SLS Discovery
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1932215 8984  9032  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 2) started; operation # 9; does use network; is not at background priority
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1933772 3044  4380  ComApi          *QUEUED* SLS Discovery
2022/05/23 13:33:40.1937395 8984  3020  IdleTimer       WU operation (CDiscoveryCall::Init ID 2, operation # 9) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2022/05/23 13:33:40.2150485 3044  3016  ComApi          *RESUMED* Discovery
2022/05/23 13:33:40.2151120 3044  3016  ComApi          Exit code = 0x00000000, Result code = 0x8024500C
2022/05/23 13:33:40.2151187 3044  3016  Api             * END *   Discovery ClientId
2022/05/23 13:33:40.2375494 3044  4380  ComApi          *FAILED* [8024500C] Method failed [CSLSClientProxy::GetSLSDataChunk:256]
2022/05/23 13:34:18.6911060 8308  8272  ComApi          * START *   Federated Search ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator (cV: hWVZBe0EMUS2JIkI.0.1.0)
2022/05/23 13:34:18.6947433 8984  9032  IdleTimer       WU operation (SR.MoUpdateOrchestrator ID 3) started; operation # 14; does use network; is not at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:18.7546353 8984  6340  IdleTimer       WU operation (SR.MoUpdateOrchestrator ID 3, operation # 14) stopped; does use network; is not at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:18.7749348 8308  1360  ComApi          Federated Search: Starting search against 1 service(s) (cV = hWVZBe0EMUS2JIkI.0.1.0)
2022/05/23 13:34:18.7750785 8308  1360  ComApi          * START *   Search ClientId = MoUpdateOrchestrator, ServiceId = 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7, Flags: 0X40010010 (cV = hWVZBe0EMUS2JIkI.0.1.0.0)
2022/05/23 13:34:18.7853853 8984  9016  IdleTimer       WU operation (CSearchCall::Init ID 4) started; operation # 17; does use network; is not at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:18.8105333 8984  9016  Reporter        OS Product Type = 0x00000030
2022/05/23 13:34:19.0988729 8984  9016  Agent           * START * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator  Id = 4]
2022/05/23 13:34:19.0988989 8984  9016  Agent           Service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 is not in sequential scan list
2022/05/23 13:34:19.0989093 8984  9016  Agent           Added service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 to sequential scan list
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1042460 8984  3060  Agent           Service 3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7 is in sequential scan list
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1055337 8984  5432  Agent           * END * Queueing Finding updates [CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator  Id = 4]
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1066319 8984  5432  Agent           * START * Finding updates CallerId = MoUpdateOrchestrator  Id = 4 (cV = hWVZBe0EMUS2JIkI.0.1.0.0.2)
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1066359 8984  5432  Agent           Online = Yes; Interactive = Yes; AllowCachedResults = No; Ignore download priority = No
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1066384 8984  5432  Agent           Criteria = CallerProfile='AUv2' and IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Installation' or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='OptionalInstallation' or IsPresent=1 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' or IsInstalled=1 and DeploymentAction='Installation' and RebootRequired=1 or IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction='Uninstallation' and RebootRequired=1""
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1066440 8984  5432  Agent           ServiceID = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7} Managed
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1066455 8984  5432  Agent           Search Scope = {Machine}
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1066508 8984  5432  Agent           Caller SID for Applicability: S-1-5-21-2077624335-2170942292-1082280470-1001
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1066524 8984  5432  Agent           ProcessDriverDeferrals is set
2022/05/23 13:34:19.1069292 8984  5432  Agent           *FAILED* [8024043D] GetIsInventoryRequired
2022/05/23 13:34:21.8061661 8984  5432  Misc            Got WSUS Client/Server URL: http://127.0.0.1:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx""
2022/05/23 13:34:21.8123702 8984  5432  WebServices     Proxy Behavior set to 1 for service url http://127.0.0.1:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2022/05/23 13:34:21.8414043 8984  5432  Driver          Skipping printer driver 3 due to incomplete info or mismatched environment - HWID[(null)] Provider[Microsoft] MfgName[Microsoft] Name[Remote Desktop Easy Print] pEnvironment[Windows x64] LocalPrintServerEnv[Windows x64]
2022/05/23 13:34:21.8414128 8984  5432  Driver          Skipping printer driver 6 due to incomplete info or mismatched environment - HWID[microsoftmicrosoft_musd] Provider[Microsoft] MfgName[Microsoft] Name[Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver] pEnvironment[Windows NT x86] LocalPrintServerEnv[Windows x64]
2022/05/23 13:34:22.3501195 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  ServiceId = {3DA21691-E39D-4DA6-8A4B-B43877BCB1B7}, Server URL = http://127.0.0.1:8530/ClientWebService/client.asmx
2022/05/23 13:34:22.3759832 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  PT: Calling GetConfig on server
2022/05/23 13:34:22.3760138 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetConfig_WithRecovery) started; operation # 18; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:22.3866070 8984  5432  WebServices     Auto proxy settings for this web service call.
2022/05/23 13:34:24.3705700 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetConfig_WithRecovery, operation # 18) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:24.4191155 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  PT: Service supports GetConfig2, Calling GetConfig2 on server
2022/05/23 13:34:24.4197507 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetConfig2_WithRecovery) started; operation # 19; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:24.5573077 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetConfig2_WithRecovery, operation # 19) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:24.5575279 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  Cached cookie has expired or new PID is available
2022/05/23 13:34:24.5576769 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetCookie_WithRecovery) started; operation # 20; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:24.7991588 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::GetCookie_WithRecovery, operation # 20) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:24.8006603 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 21; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:25.1474646 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 21) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:25.1478043 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:25.1478180 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:25.1601901 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 22; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:25.3176227 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 22) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:25.3188682 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:25.3188886 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:25.3677697 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 23; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:25.7460993 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 23) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:25.7467375 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:25.7467548 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:28.2524743 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 24; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:28.4030992 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 24) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:28.4036223 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:28.4036357 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:28.9186100 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 25; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:28.9797501 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 25) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:28.9805660 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:28.9807704 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:29.1306853 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 26; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:29.2018041 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 26) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:29.2030419 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:29.2030843 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:29.4690168 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 27; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:29.4846814 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 27) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:29.4849645 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:29.4849820 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:29.6077428 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 28; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:29.6166791 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 28) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:34:29.6169247 8984  5432  Metadata        Policy-driven service enabled. Using Ignore Policy.
2022/05/23 13:34:29.6169437 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates - 0 bad out of 0 metadata signatures checked using Unknown enforcement mode (raw mode: (null)).
2022/05/23 13:34:29.6739735 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover) started; operation # 29; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:36:31.4598442 8984  9000  Shared          Power status changed
2022/05/23 13:36:31.8348323 8984  9056  DownloadManager Received power state change notification: Old: AC; New: AC.
2022/05/23 13:36:54.7138763 8984  5432  WebServices     *FAILED* [8007000E] Failed in ::ToBstr(&Xml, dest.Xml)
2022/05/23 13:36:54.8902095 8984  5432  WebServices     *FAILED* [8007000E] Failed in (FromNwsStructPointerArray<SusUpdateInfo, ClientService::UpdateInfo>)( &__NewUpdates_nSizeIs, &NewUpdates, dest.NewUpdatesCount, dest.NewUpdates)
2022/05/23 13:36:54.8902313 8984  5432  WebServices     *FAILED* [8007000E] Failed in SyncUpdatesResult->FromNws(*_result)
2022/05/23 13:36:54.9162931 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  *FAILED* [8007000E] SyncUpdates_WithRecovery failed
2022/05/23 13:36:54.9359508 8984  5432  IdleTimer       WU operation (CAgentProtocolTalker::SyncUpdates_WithRecover, operation # 29) stopped; does use network; is at background priority
2022/05/23 13:36:54.9456684 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  SyncUpdates round trips: 9
2022/05/23 13:36:54.9456734 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  *FAILED* [8007000E] Sync of Updates
2022/05/23 13:36:54.9648153 8984  5432  ProtocolTalker  *FAILED* [8007000E] SyncServerUpdatesInternal failed
```

I searched for `windows update 0x8007000e` and it's mentioned on [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/error-0x8007000e-from-windows-update-failing-to/cc60f6b6-acf8-4cd1-9e50-9f15ffd12950) that I should:

```
Run Sfc /scannow, then dism.exe and sfc /scannow again.

Retry Windows 10 Update
```

I run these commands, but no problem is found:

```perl
PS C:\Users\user> sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
PS C:\Users\user> dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.19041.844

Image Version: 10.0.19043.1288

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.
PS C:\Users\user> sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.
```

I restart the machine and check for updates again, but I face the same error and see the same logs. How can I fix this?

Windows specifications:

```
Edition: Windows 10 Pro
Version: 21H1
```